# Why do Asgardians use swords?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-marvel, thor-the-dark-world

In *Thor: The Dark World*, the Asgardians clearly have advanced technology, as they are using anti-aircraft missiles against the dark elves' ships in the city. But when the dark elves get inside the main Asgardian building, the Asgardians are just standing around with their swords up, and are easily killed by the dark elves who are using gun-like weapons.

Why don't they have more realistic weapons to defend their king?

Comment: Are they actually swords? Maybe the weapons are so advanced we can only perceive them as swords.

Comment: Well, regardless of whether they are actually swords, they just stood there and died while the dark elves shot at them.

Comment: This might be opion based actually...

Comment: Could be something as simple as honor - Asgardians seem the type to relish hand-to-hand combat and not care much for projectile-based weapons, anti-aircraft missiles aside.

Comment: In the hands of an expert, a sword is a formidable CQB weapon. It doesn't 'run out of ammo' but is too short range. The only ranging weapons seems to be Gungnir and Mjölnir. Even sticking to Norse mythos, they could have used archers to great effect. A whole bunch of 'Legolas' level archers could really make a mess.

Comment: I seem to remember their bladed weapons possed some form of energy charge. Especially in the fight between Frigga and Malakeith, I remember her blade glows blue and makes a distinct "singing" sound akin to a Lightsaber.  This could be a case of her being the Queen of the Aesir granting her greater ability than say Sif or another Shield Maiden.

Comment: @Monty129: It wasn’t just Frigga’s sword. For example, the soldiers in the training ground or the first war with the Dark Elves have the same lightning-like effect.

Comment: You watch a movie about English-speaking superhumans from another planet that play god on Earth and you ask for "realistic" weaponry? Oh, I hope that was just a bad choice of words. :D

Comment: @Raphael: that is the only correct answer.

Comment: @Raphael Would practical have been a better word?

Comment: @Zoe: Definitely! (Just like their fireplace. :X)

Comment: Because they want to.

Comment: Jedi and Sith use that, too.

Comment: Palace guards in most cities are largely dressed and armed for ceremony.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Asgardians do have and use energy weapons.  But keep in mind that Asgardians are usually rather strong and would most likely benefit more from using high tech melee weapons..

Asgardian racial information from the wiki..

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asgardians_(comics)

> Although they look human, all Asgardians possess certain superhuman
>   physical attributes. They are extremely long-lived (though not purely
>   immortal like their Olympian counterparts), aging at an extremely slow
>   rate upon reaching adulthood (through the periodic consumption of the
>   golden apples of Idunn). Asgardian flesh and bone is three times
>   denser than similar human tissue, contributing to their superhuman
>   strength and weight. An average Asgardian male can lift 30 tons (27.2
>   metric tons); an average Asgardian female can lift about 25 tons (22.7
>   metric tons). Asgardians are immune to all terrestrial diseases and
>   resistant to conventional injury. The metabolism of the Asgardians
>   gives them superhuman stamina in all physical activities.

Remember the Asgard is one of the most powerful races in the movie universe as far as this point, and the dark elves no longer existed according to Asgardian lore.  So most likely they thought that the intruders wouldn't not have the sufficient technology or strength to defeat them.

Essentially Asgardians use their technology to enhance their armor and melee weapons so that they can take advantage of their superhuman abilities.

Comment: For someone sufficiently strong and with sufficiently tough skin (such as the Asgardians, who could shrug off regular bullets, especially if armored) melee weapons are a superior choice: a fine edge will part skin/armor which would stop a larger impact site (like knives cut Kevlar) and could be driven by their increased strength.  I think it's likely that a sword swing by someone who can deadlift 25 tons will pack more energy than a bullet.

Comment: Unless you are a heavily trained person with firearms, in which you can shoot a person in the head with dead aim accuracy and know that the blast will go through their head / skin.

Comment: Hard to pull off a head-shot in combat, when everyone is moving.  There's also no reason to expect a head-shot to penetrate if an arm-shot or a leg-shot won't - the skull is a thick piece of bone, and the skin isn't notably thinner there than anywhere else.  By the way, most gun training trains a person to aim for the center of mass (torso) - it's the largest, stablest target and a hit there will almost certainly be incapacitating.  Head shots are best left to snipers, video games, and zombie apocalypses.

Comment: A (heavy) spear thrown by an Asgardian would have advantages similar to the swung sword, plus the range advantage. And if they know at all how Mjølner works and can replicate the effect, it could even come back. (But then, show me the consistent Sci-Fi/Fantasy/Mythology universe.)

Comment: @Jeff For some reason, when people say of superheros "lift X tons" for some reason I always think of overhead press. Mostly because you always see them cleaning things overhead and throwing them off the horizon.

Comment: What about the Chitauri? They had firearms. And even if the Asgardians didn't think they were going to be fighting opponents with firearms, that doesn't preclude them from bringing a gun to proverbial knife fight.

Comment: Side comment:  @DoctorWho22's answer sounds an awful lot like "Your superior intellect is no match for our puny weapons."  :)

Comment: @Jeff, then why did they whomped by the Dark Elves? They didn't just lose; they were massacred.

Comment: @PaulDraper: I haven't seen the movie yet, so I can't speak to the scene.  But the Asgardians aren't immune to morale, surprise, magic, or other 'conventional' tactics.  If the Dark Elves have weapons that can hurt an Asgardian, it shouldn't be tough to massacre them, given the right circumstances.

Comment: @Jeff When I earlier spoke about knowing that the blast will go  through head / skin I meant if an enemy had a weapon that is sufficient enough to go through Asgardian tissue / bone.  Yes you are right most gun training is center of mass but that's only because it's to stop people from moving.

Answer (score 10):

Don't forget what happened when Odin walked in on the Dark Elves...  He leveled a small party of them with a half-second of a ray from his staff.  (This is a long-distance, "gun-like" weapon.)

They also had heavy artillery mounted for shooting down aerial attacks, and they had gun-like devices mounted on their own aircraft.

This leads me to think that they simply carry melee weapons because they find them easier to fight with for the small types of attacks they are likely to see in everyday action.  They probably have long-range weapons, but they aren't used for handling small uprisings (as Asgardians are pretty strong, and can deal with a lot anyway.)

Comment: Long range weapons like the Bifröst? True, somewhat: why move troops with guns into a battle if you can drop a nuke?

Answer (score 10):

I think it also needs to be mentioned that those Dark Elf "guns" were CRAZY powerful relative to everything else we've seen in the MCU.

Remember the fight between Thor and Iron Man in *The Avengers*?  He took several hits from Iron Man's repulsor blasts ***to the face***, and it didn't even knock him down.  Those repulsors have been shown to destroy Chitauri sleds and the Jericho missile system, let alone Extremis soldiers and Hammer Drones, in one hit.  And Thor *didn't even fall down*.

Asgardians are tough as hell.

Plus, not many people mention it, but Asgardian shields did block those Dark Elf energy blasts.  Watch closely and you'll see them shimmer blue and dissipate the energy.  The blasts only killed the soldiers when they hit them straight-on, missing the shields.

I think this has less to do with "projectile vs melee," and more to do with the Dark Elves being way tougher than the average enemy of an Asgardian solder.  When you're tough enough to take most weapons that most enemies can throw at you, without even the benefit of armor, it opens the door to using more "ceremonial" or traditional weapons being used at most times, because the need for something better isn't really there.  But then when an ancient evil returns with a vengeance, it can catch you off-guard.

So basically, they use swords because usually that's all they need.  But the Dark Elves were an uncommonly powerful enemy.

Answer (score 8):

Three points:

- Asgardians *had the technology* for projectile weapons (Bifrost, defense towers).
- Adgardians *had good cause* to have projectile weapons (Dark Elves, Chitauri).
- Their *swords were inferior* to projectile weapons. (Based on the fact that a highly trained army of demigods using swords got absolutely slaughtered on their own turf by an enemy they outnumbered.)

It's reasonable then, to assume, that for one reason or another they **chose** not to use projectile weapons.

Asgardians live and die by honor. It is very likely, to Asgardians, swords are more honorable (ethical) for personal combat than guns.

A human analogy might be hollow-point bullets, which have been prohibited for use in war as far back as the [Hague Convention of 1899](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hague_Conventions_%281899_and_1907%29). Hollow-points are very effective at causing pain and death, and they would make war far more painful for your opponent. They are in the technical sense better, yet most nations adhere to this ban, and many (most?) people agree they are "more unethical" to use in war.

Asgardians, like humans, deliberately chose not to use technically superior weapons out of honor/ethics.

---

EDIT: I don't mean to say that the Asgardians signed some sort of wartime accords. I mean that people often choose inferior weapon out of honor/ethics. The situations are different, but it makes the idea seem a little less absurd.

Comment: The last two paragraphs are pretty irrelevant. There's certainly no canon reason to assume that guns are banned in Asgardian society simply because they choose not to use them.

Comment: @Richard, no one said Asgardian weapons are banned by law. But certainly they *choose* not to us them. The last two paragraphs give examples of humans choosing not to use better weapons. (True, both examples are official legal agreements, but that's not what is significant...it's choosing to use inferior weapons.)

Comment: Per Monty's comment above, I don't think we can assume that their weapons are inferior simply because they have a different style of fighting. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cx1XhlPIeEM

Comment: @Richard, no one thinks a weapon is inferior "because they have a different style of fighting". They think a weapon is inferior if the highly skilled, highly trained demigods using them get their a**** handed to them.

Comment: @PaulDraper Actually, hollowpoint bullets kill quicker due to greater tissue damage and hydrostatic shock, rarely exiting the victim. Non-hollowpoint bullets tend to punch a small hole through the victim and keep on going. Civilians use hollowpoints because of the reduced danger of overpenetration. Soldiers use non-hollowpoints because it is a greater tactical advantage if you wound your enemy, rather than kill.

Comment: @pleurocoelus, yes that's all generally accepted. I think you could win a war faster by making your enemy use body bags instead of bandages, but I know that opinion is not universal.

Comment: @PaulDraper I think the logic is that it ties up resources caring for the wounded, many of whom might never be able to fight again. Of course, that logic would not work if your enemy left their own wounded for dead.

Comment: @pleurocoelus, yeah that's the conventional wisdom.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: the movie doesn't follow comics facts.

In the comics, the Dark elves don't use any laser guns, they use swords and magic just like the Asgardians. The easiest way to kill an Asgardian, definitely isn't by laser guns, since they are highly durable against any energy projection. So, the best way would be by piercing objects such as spears...
The Asgardians use swords because it is the best way of killing other high alien beings.

Comment: Can you cite some references for this? Why would swords hurt them if lasers and other items can't? And if the answer is "magic" swords, can't they have "magic" bullets or lasers? Or "magic" chain-mail to stop the swords?

Comment: Only some dark elves use magic... Some quick research shows that their powers show this.  Dark elves possess gifted intellects, as well as superhuman strength, speed, stamina, durability, agility, and reflexes. Some Dark Elves, like Malekith, can use faire magic do shapeshift, teleport, project energy blasts, and so on.  Which is similar actually to the movie considering Malekith is the only one shown using magic.  http://marvel.wikia.com/Dark_Elves

Comment: Many writers Think that the Asgardians, Dark elves, the freaking frost giants are magical beings so the laws of physic don't apply to them that's why they can almost survive any kind of alien laser guns but be pierced by regular bullets and swords if driven with some superhuman strength.

Comment: Thor being many, many, many, many.... times stronger and more durable than any Asgardian can take any bullet quite easily although some dumb writers made him have some problems with bullets.

Comment: Not all Asgardians can practice magic just as not all dark elves can although they are all considered magical beings by nature.

Answer (score 0):

When you have superhuman strength and durability, then  why use a simple gun? I mean, with at least the power of a jackhammer in your arms ( I'm making an estimate on Asgardian strength based on what was posted and from what I read on  the link) why put that behind a trigger finger? It wouldn't make much sense for a race that can lift at least 30 tons to need to hide behind cover , pull a trigger, and hope to get a lucky shot in someones face or center mass when they can just slice, crush or rip them apart and keep going.